# Process 'command 'NDK PATH' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to add this [library](https://github.com/ragnraok/android-image-filter) to my app, but when I run the app I get this error :

> Process 'command 'D:\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

Build.Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 28
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs 'src'
            res {
                srcDirs 'res'
            }
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            jni.srcDirs = []
            jniLibs.srcDir 'libs'
        }
    }

    task ndkBuild(type:Exec) {
        workingDir file('./')
        commandLine getNdkBuildCmd()
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }

    task cleanJni(type:Exec) {
        workingDir file('./')
        commandLine getNdkBuildCmd(), 'clean'
    }

    clean.dependsOn cleanJni

}
def getNdkBuildCmd() {
    def ndkbuild = "D:\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle\\ndk-build.cmd"
    return ndkbuild
}
```

Path :

[image]

Comment: What's the error? The "error message" that you included here just says "there was an error". It's not the useful part of the error message. You need to include the full error message for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Modify this function to give drive name 'D\'

```
def getNdkBuildCmd() {
    def ndkbuild = "D\:\\Sdk\\ndk-bundle\\ndk-build.cmd"
    return ndkbuild
}
```